# Detect stop with Ruby Daemons gem

Tags: ruby, daemon

I'm using the ruby [daemon](http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/daemons/) gem. Wondering how I can add some extra steps to the stop action? Was hoping I could detect stop was called, and add some extra code to it. Anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the daemon gem code, it doesn't look like it has an obvious extension point for this purpose. However, I wonder if (in the daemonized process) you could trap the KILL/TERM signal that daemons sends when a 'stop' occurs...?

```
trap("TERM") do
  # execute your extra code here
end
```

Alternatively you could install an at_exit hook :-

```
at_exit do
  # execute your extra code here
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Rapleaf had [a pretty good article on their blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20090525050606/http://blog.rapleaf.com/dev/?p=19) about an extension to the Daemons gem that might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

After reading Daemons docs I found that there is a `:stop_proc` option in the [#run method](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/daemons/Daemons.run)

> :stop_proc A proc that will be called when the daemonized process
>   receives a request to stop (works only for :load and :proc mode)

So basically you can pass it as an option with the [#run](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/daemons/Daemons.run) or [#run_proc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/daemons/Daemons.run_proc) methods

<sub>[Original answer's link to rubyforge](https://web.archive.org/web/http://daemons.rubyforge.org:80/Daemons.html#method-c-run)</sub>